# Simulating TEC current control input for MAX1969 Peltier driver

Tags: thermistor, peltier

I am trying to simulate the control loop used to drive the CTLI pin of MAX1969 shown in the figure. In this application, a DAC is used to set the temperature. I used a regular resistor to represent the thermistor at a given point in time. In the simulation, the output to CTLI is fluctuating. Similar results with LTSpice. I'm starting to think that this cannot be simulated without including the MAX1969 in the simulation as well. I'm curious why that is. Unfortunately, there's no SPICE model for the MAX1969.

From the datasheet on page 12 it seems that
ITEC = (VCTLI-1.50) / (10*RSENSE)

So, VCTLI = ITEC*10*RESENSE + 1.5

[Simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWc0DscBMkDMBOHAWOAydEBSMsihAUwFowwAoAJxDXxHXU45C0xRw8SEwCG7SJwT5OADgBs02SBzgkDJGBFwo0MFgWHuKdCkI5IcnHL0GjDw08e3tIpgHdJ0sKT4J0W1EvfwUKPgUeKE9vEEj5JTio4JBFTnjUxJlOFL4BcKkyX2iJawUQfDBylACKqtV1EE1hHWR0PDk0BXJ8BARTTjBoLBb4VnZa-DkKOSmK6aE3MbYy%20YptUzXF9y9V-AFUnHKpihS9hdnbE%20ivDdJru7IVFMfszOUcpgA3cBxSI64clsANOFXW0CQoJgCCYAHNfv9ylUKCDopgUIDgeUsIZVMdkAgAGoAfQASgBRABiTHRsW4vEKYBQ%20KGRLJVO%204GZ4DC-EZvNBhGQIyhELhXKRvORPKhNMgGKw-IohlcvM4ABVyQBZAAKxIAyuT1XKMXtdDhuYQKBrtXrDcavGErvUnVtRGxXdd9vcFtQlu64lY6uUEMVKuV1u4AMZFe71b3BoQwHQQRjQfZTGp-SAIASmNTJyDMEKTF0IY71FLdCvlatumJ166e33ifgKK4A%20kVAGuDRgLQ6cHkOAoTqKlA2XoqVmjOAmtu2UP3A5LioEkkU6leBPXFX17cHcMLxMpPdHs8trxn%20p7rCzaIx2-3rt3nJcaDoejA4YoLD9uT9PEswkHocDFlwUSvhBnD4CCMRPpwt6CAGSHKoU%20RCDw0Z8ohggvshoEiHgxEkaReAVLA2AAXIWA1LBvg4BAhbgfhFAvveoi0l2sGStaAKcAAwuqAAyACSTAAA7Qd25RduW6xJuKcm8nJfyKSWPrhKWEbjPJ-CCAomwYZGc7wnpGE8fpsoAB5kAgajtCMhkjO0%20JROqAAWNAsAAtgAlgAzgALgA9iwDZGYIeTIZJsQYaOuEKac4oJVZqS6MZ0RAA)

Datesheet pg. 14:

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX1968-MAX1969.pdf
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are only testing the NTC, a simple test in spice would be to sweep the resistance of the NTC open loop. You can then check the voltage an make sure it's acceptable for the MAX1969. You can also use a B source and include a temperature to resistance function if you want to close the loop. If you know what the MAX1969 does with PWM you could potentially replicate that in spice but that may prove more difficult.